# .Net DataTable Select as Sql Brackets

Tags: .net, filter, datatable

Is there a wildcard form to assume İ and I as same characters for .net datatable.select function as sql brackets do?

For example this SQL query returns either 'JESSİCA' or 'JESSICA'

select * from Customers where name = 'JESS[Iİ]CA'.

Comment: No that query does not.  You need to use like (not =) for [].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your life easier and  use `LINQ-TO-DataTable`:

```
var query = from row in dataTable.AsEnumerable()
            let name = row.Field<string>("name")
            where name == "JESSİCA" || name == "JESSICA"
            select row;
```

If you want a new  `DataTable` use `CopyToDataTable()`, if you want a `DataRow[]` use `ToArray()`.

If you want to compare case-insensitve and the list of accepted names can increase:

```
string names = { "JESSİCA", "JESSICA" };
var query = from row in dataTable.AsEnumerable()
            let name = row.Field<string>("name")
            where names.Contains(name, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
            select row;
```